# How to set up squid3 to respond with cache if back end server is down

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, squid

I have a squid3 proxy set up at the moment as a transparent proxy. i am using the following in my config:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
acl localnet src 10.234.255.68/24
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
http_access allow all
http_access allow localhost
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 5000 16 256
```

though if i shut down the apache backend server for maintenance, squid can no longer displays anything at all, just a squid error page.

i would like squid to present the cached version of any requests if it cannot reach the back end server.

is this possible? if so, could somebody point me in the right direction.